# Problems with making a Caesar Cipher code

Tags: javascript

I tried to code a Ceasar Cipher coder as an exercise in school.
I have encountered a problem where the letters x, y, and z come out as undefined.

```js
function txtcipher() {
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var txtlen = txt.length;
  var txtciphered = "";
  var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for (x = 0; x < txtlen; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < alphabet.length; y++) {
      if (txt[x] === alphabet[y]) {
        txtciphered += alphabet[y + 3];
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("cpher").value = txtciphered;
  console.log(txtciphered);
}
```

```html
<input id="txt" />
<button onclick="txtcipher()">Check</button><br />
<input type="text" id="cpher" readonly></input>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caesar Cipher work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20445039/caesar-cipher-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stay in the bounds of array length of `alphabet` array

Instead of

```
y + 3
```

use

```
(y + 3) % alphabet.length
```

```js
function txtcipher() {
  var txt = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var txtlen = txt.length;
  var txtciphered = "";
  var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  for (x = 0; x < txtlen; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < alphabet.length; y++) {
      if (txt[x] === alphabet[y]) {
        txtciphered += alphabet[(y + 3) % alphabet.length];
      }
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("cpher").value = txtciphered;
  console.log(txtciphered);
}
```

```html
<input id="txt"  value="xyzabc"/>
<button onclick="txtcipher()">Check</button><br />
<input type="text" id="cpher" readonly placeholder="abcdef <-- xyzabc"></input>
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me how (y + 3) % alphabet.length works? I would really appreciate it if you do.

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator: so when you exceed the range eg. `27` the expression returns `27%26 = 1` so `x, y, z` are mapped to  `a, b, c`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder

Comment: Maybe this example can help you understand the Remainder operator: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/VwYJwNX?editors=0010

Answer (score 1):

You are just going out of array bounds - here:

```
txtciphered += alphabet[y + 3];
```

when `y` is bigger than `alphabet.length - 3`